# arrays, constructors and instances

Tags: c++, arrays, class, arduino

I explain my problem: I'm trying to solve an arrays proble, I got a programme done in OOP in which it has a class called lights. What I want is to do an array with pin numbers inside and set them up as output. I did pin by pin and it was easy to do but now I would like to do it with a for loop and an array
I don't know how to build a constructors and handle of this with an array whit pin numbers in it.

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class lights{

  int pins[5]; //array for 5 elements
  int i; 

  public:
  lights(int ledPins[]){

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){     //pins are set up as output
      pinMode(pins[i],OUTPUT);
    }

  }//end constructor


  void attempt(){                        //metodo para pobrar si se enciende los leds

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
      digitalWrite(pins[i],HIGH);
      Serial.println(pins[i]);
    }
  }//end attempt
};//end class
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int MyPins[] = {5,6,7,8,9};        //I declare what it is inside

lights lit(MyPins);                 //I create an objet with my array as parameters

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  lit.attempt();

}
```

Comment: Java and C++ are two very different languages. Pick one.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  OP has tagged the question for both java and c++, is what Sam is referring to

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put everything into a class.  I think using a class for the lights is overkill.

In my experience, a functions are used to process the light pins and they all would take a pin enum.

Unless you have a huge amount of pins to set up, a loop may not be worthwhile.  Unrolling the loop may increase the programs efficiency:

```
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
```

Initialization usually only occurs once, so optimization is usually not warranted.

If need to use classes, I suggest one class that *models* a single light.

Every light has an associated pin.

You can have a container of lights (such as array):

```
class Light
{
  public:  
    Light(unsigned int pin)
      : m_pin(pin),
        m_is_on(false)
    { ; }

    void initialize(); // Sets up the appropriate pin
    void on(); // Turns on the light
    void off(); // Turns off the light
    void blink(unsigned int rate, unsigned int duration);

  private:
     unsigned int m_pin;
     bool         m_is_on;
};

Light display[] = {Light(5), Light(6), Light(7), Light(8), Light(9)};
const unsigned int light_quantity =
    sizeof(display) / sizeof(display[0]);
```

An advantage to this model is that your program can be in terms of *lights* and not worry about pins.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are just writing code but didnt make an algorithm to design the application first...

Take a minute to see what you wrote as a software...
you are passing to the constructor an array, but where are you using that information??  nowhere...

```
 lights(int ledPins[]){

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){     //pins are set up as output
      pinMode(pins[i],OUTPUT);
    }

  }//end constructor
```

and you are setting as output in the arduino the pins `{0 to 4}` and not `{5 to 9}` as you think, after that the **loop** method is just setting to HIGH level pins that probably dont even have LEds :)

(you should there by the way use a sleep and play turning the leds on an off so you can see how they blink )

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem: just two lines were missing. I correct the real constructor

```
public:
  lights(int ledPins[]){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){    
      pines[i] = ledPines[i];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){     //pins are set up as output
      pinMode(pins[i],OUTPUT);
    }

  }//end constructor
```